# In Bash, how do I add a literal \n after each line?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I have a file which contains URL's separated by new lines.

After each URL, I would like to insert the literal character "\n".

How can I do so?

Comment: To be sure I understand: you want to add the two characters backslash then n at the end of each line?

Comment: You keep saying character (singular), but backslash and n are two characters.

Comment: string literal backslash **then** `n` or character literal newline?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i.BAK 's/$/\\n/' files

perl -i.BAK -pe 's/$/\\n/' files
```

Answer (score 1):

check this example:

```
kent$  seq 5|sed 's/$/\\n/'
1\n                        
2\n
3\n
4\n
5\n
```